# Determine which wire goes to which connection?

Tags: soldering, repair

I am repairing a pair of headphones that had one earpiece come out (poor workmanship sadly...). They have two wires and two connections to solder them to, but I don't see an easy way to tell which goes to which.

Is there a way I can do so easily without trying one and having to redo it if it's wrong?  Is it possible they can go to either one?  One wire is red, one is gold, but I don't see any differentiation on the connection on the earpiece.

Also, should I attempt to remove the old solder (or even melt it and reuse it?) or is it okay in this kind of situation to solder over it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You could open up the other side and compare, or just try it both ways on a source with good spatial separation of instruments or voices and see which sounds better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio signal is AC, so soldering the wires on either way should *function*.

However, the phase of the audio output will depend on the wiring orientation. One of those wires is ground, and the other is the signal. Depending on which way you solder them to the speaker, the speaker cone will either push out or pull in with the same input signal. If you wire it such that the right headphone speaker is pushing out while the left one is pulling in, it might sound wrong. It might also be inaudible. If you can, open up the working side of the headphones and see how they did it there.

If you simply melt the solder that's there, there will be little or no flux to clean any oxides off the metal surfaces, and you may end up with a 'cold' joint. It would be best to add fresh flux, or fresh solder that contains flux.

As far as joints go, this is about as easy as soldering rework can get. Test it before reassembling. Then if you have to reverse the orientation, it will be quite easy.

Comment: @Joe , for doing a phasing test, use a mono source. Try connecting wires both ways. The proper way will produced sound that seems to come from the centre of your head. The improper way produces sound that seems to come from outside your head.

Comment: Good point. The 'improper'

Comment: Accidentally submitted the comment before finishing and apparently I can't edit or delete it. Oh well.

The 'improper' way has applications in sound art.

Comment: Thanks.  Apparently got it right on the first try (lucky, or else it didn't matter within my ability to tell).